# Putting tables into two columns in a responsive webpage

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on a class project and I am almost done, however I cannot get my calendar page to work properly. I am supposed to create each calendar month using tables, so no javascript or arrays. The calendar pages also needs to be responsive.

I already made each month as a table and I need to put these tables into 2 columns. The issue is that the columns are uneven and I attached a screenshot below to show my problem. I want January - June on the left side and July-December on the right side. I am confused on how to do this.

Each month is also supposed to have text listing important dates right next them. For example: 1st: New Years and 18:Martin Luther King Day should be next to the January table. When I try to put the text in the html code, I can never get the text to align properly. They were either below the tables or underneath them. I even tried tied putting all the text and calendar tables into one big table with four columns. I liked how it look, however I could not get this to be responsive since the table fell off the page in mobile view.

I would appreciate any help I can get.

```css
CSS

.Calendar, th,td{
   color: black;
   border: 1px solid navy;
   background-color: #add8e6;
   border-collapse: collapse;
   margin-bottom:1%;
   margin-top:1%;
  
}

.eventDay{
   background-color:red;
}

.column{
   -moz-column-count: 2;
   -webkit-column-count: 2;
   column-count: 2;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
   .column{
   -moz-column-count: 1;
   -webkit-column-count: 1;
   column-count: 1;
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="column">
<table class="Calendar">
  <tr>
  <th colspan="7">January 2021</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Sun</th> 
    <th>Mon</th>
    <th>Tues</th>
    <th>Wed</th>
    <th>Thurs</th>
    <th>Fri</th> 
    <th>Sat</th> 
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">1</td></div>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>17</td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">18</td></div>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>28</td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">29</td></div>
    <td>30</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>31</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr> 
  </table>

   <table class="Calendar">
  <tr>
  <th colspan="7">February 2021</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Sun</th> 
    <th>Mon</th>
    <th>Tues</th>
    <th>Wed</th>
    <th>Thurs</th>
    <th>Fri</th> 
    <th>Sat</th> 
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>14</td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">15</td></div>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>28</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  </table>

  <table class="Calendar">
  <tr>
  <th colspan="7">March 2021</th>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <th>Sun</th> 
    <th>Mon</th>
    <th>Tues</th>
    <th>Wed</th>
    <th>Thurs</th>
    <th>Fri</th> 
    <th>Sat</th> 
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">26</td></div>
    <td>27</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>28</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>31</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  
 <table class="Calendar">
  <tr>
  <th colspan="7">April 2021</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Sun</th> 
    <th>Mon</th>
    <th>Tues</th>
    <th>Wed</th>
    <th>Thurs</th>
    <th>Fri</th> 
    <th>Sat</th> 
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">2</td></div>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>28</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
   </table>
   
 <table class="Calendar">
  <tr>
  <th colspan="7">May 2021</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Sun</th> 
    <th>Mon</th>
    <th>Tues</th>
    <th>Wed</th>
    <th>Thurs</th>
    <th>Fri</th> 
    <th>Sat</th> 
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>15</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">28</td></div>
    <td>29</td>
  </tr>
 
 <tr>
    <td>30</td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">31</td></div>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="Calendar">
  <tr>
  <th colspan="7">June 2021</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Sun</th> 
    <th>Mon</th>
    <th>Tues</th>
    <th>Wed</th>
    <th>Thurs</th>
    <th>Fri</th> 
    <th>Sat</th> 
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">12</td></div>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td><div class="eventDay">13</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">14</td></div>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>26</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>28</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr> 
</table>
 </th>

<div class="column"> 
<table class="Calendar">
  <tr>
  <th colspan="7">July 2021</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Sun</th> 
    <th>Mon</th>
    <th>Tues</th>
    <th>Wed</th>
    <th>Thurs</th>
    <th>Fri</th> 
    <th>Sat</th> 
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td><div class="eventDay">4</td></div>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">10</td></div>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td><div class="eventDay">11</td></div>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>28</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">30</td></div>
    <td>31</td>
  </tr>
 </table> 
 
  <table class="Calendar">
  <tr>
  <th colspan="7">August 2021</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Sun</th> 
    <th>Mon</th>
    <th>Tues</th>
    <th>Wed</th>
    <th>Thurs</th>
    <th>Fri</th> 
    <th>Sat</th> 
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">7</td></div>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td><div class="eventDay">8</td></div>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>21</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>28</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>31</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  
  <table class="Calendar">
  <tr>
  <th colspan="7">September 2021</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Sun</th> 
    <th>Mon</th>
    <th>Tues</th>
    <th>Wed</th>
    <th>Thurs</th>
    <th>Fri</th> 
    <th>Sat</th> 
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">6</td></div>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">24</td></div>
    <td>25</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>28</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  
 <table class="Calendar">
  <tr>
  <th colspan="7">October 2021</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Sun</th> 
    <th>Mon</th>
    <th>Tues</th>
    <th>Wed</th>
    <th>Thurs</th>
    <th>Fri</th> 
    <th>Sat</th> 
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">11</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">12</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">13</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">14</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">15</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">16</td></div>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td><div class="eventDay">17</td></div>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>28</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>30</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>31</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  
  <table class="Calendar">
  <tr>
  <th colspan="7">November 2021</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Sun</th> 
    <th>Mon</th>
    <th>Tues</th>
    <th>Wed</th>
    <th>Thurs</th>
    <th>Fri</th> 
    <th>Sat</th> 
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">11</td></div>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">24</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">25</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">26</td></div>
    <td>27</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>28</td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">29</td></div>
    <td>30</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  
 <table class="Calendar">
<tr>
  <th colspan="7">December 2021</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Sun</th> 
    <th>Mon</th>
    <th>Tues</th>
    <th>Wed</th>
    <th>Thurs</th>
    <th>Fri</th> 
    <th>Sat</th> 
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">1</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">2</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">3</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">4</td></div>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td><div class="eventDay">5</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">6</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">7</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">8</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">9</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">10</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">11</td></div>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td><div class="eventDay">12</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">13</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">14</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">15</td></div>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">25</td></div>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td><div class="eventDay">26</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">27</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">28</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">29</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">30</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">31</td></div>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
 </th>
 </div>
 </div>
```

[screenshot of calendar tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29M3H.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve your problem

```css
.Calendar, th,td{
   color: black;
   border: 1px solid navy;
   background-color: #add8e6;
   border-collapse: collapse;
   margin-bottom:1%;
   margin-top:1%;
  
}
.div_left, div_right {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.row_main {display: flex; justify-content: space-around;}

.eventDay{
   background-color:red;
}

.column{
   -moz-column-count: 2;
   -webkit-column-count: 2;
   column-count: 2;
   display: flex;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
   .column{
   -moz-column-count: 1;
   -webkit-column-count: 1;
   column-count: 1;
   }
  .row_main { flex-flow:column;}
}
```

```html
  <div class="row_main">
<div class="column">
<div class="div_left">
<table class="Calendar">
  <tr>
  <th colspan="7">January 2021</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Sun</th> 
    <th>Mon</th>
    <th>Tues</th>
    <th>Wed</th>
    <th>Thurs</th>
    <th>Fri</th> 
    <th>Sat</th> 
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">1</td></div>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>17</td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">18</td></div>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>28</td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">29</td></div>
    <td>30</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>31</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr> 
  </table>

   <table class="Calendar">
  <tr>
  <th colspan="7">February 2021</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Sun</th> 
    <th>Mon</th>
    <th>Tues</th>
    <th>Wed</th>
    <th>Thurs</th>
    <th>Fri</th> 
    <th>Sat</th> 
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>14</td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">15</td></div>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>28</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  </table>

  <table class="Calendar">
  <tr>
  <th colspan="7">March 2021</th>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <th>Sun</th> 
    <th>Mon</th>
    <th>Tues</th>
    <th>Wed</th>
    <th>Thurs</th>
    <th>Fri</th> 
    <th>Sat</th> 
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">26</td></div>
    <td>27</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>28</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>31</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  
 <table class="Calendar">
  <tr>
  <th colspan="7">April 2021</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Sun</th> 
    <th>Mon</th>
    <th>Tues</th>
    <th>Wed</th>
    <th>Thurs</th>
    <th>Fri</th> 
    <th>Sat</th> 
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">2</td></div>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>28</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
   </table>
   
 <table class="Calendar">
  <tr>
  <th colspan="7">May 2021</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Sun</th> 
    <th>Mon</th>
    <th>Tues</th>
    <th>Wed</th>
    <th>Thurs</th>
    <th>Fri</th> 
    <th>Sat</th> 
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>15</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">28</td></div>
    <td>29</td>
  </tr>
 
 <tr>
    <td>30</td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">31</td></div>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="Calendar">
  <tr>
  <th colspan="7">June 2021</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Sun</th> 
    <th>Mon</th>
    <th>Tues</th>
    <th>Wed</th>
    <th>Thurs</th>
    <th>Fri</th> 
    <th>Sat</th> 
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">12</td></div>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td><div class="eventDay">13</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">14</td></div>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>26</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>28</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr> 
</table>
 </th>
</div>
  </div>
<div class="column"> 
  <div class="div_right">
<table class="Calendar">
  <tr>
  <th colspan="7">July 2021</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Sun</th> 
    <th>Mon</th>
    <th>Tues</th>
    <th>Wed</th>
    <th>Thurs</th>
    <th>Fri</th> 
    <th>Sat</th> 
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td><div class="eventDay">4</td></div>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">10</td></div>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td><div class="eventDay">11</td></div>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>28</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">30</td></div>
    <td>31</td>
  </tr>
 </table> 
 
  <table class="Calendar">
  <tr>
  <th colspan="7">August 2021</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Sun</th> 
    <th>Mon</th>
    <th>Tues</th>
    <th>Wed</th>
    <th>Thurs</th>
    <th>Fri</th> 
    <th>Sat</th> 
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">7</td></div>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td><div class="eventDay">8</td></div>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>21</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>28</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>31</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  
  <table class="Calendar">
  <tr>
  <th colspan="7">September 2021</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Sun</th> 
    <th>Mon</th>
    <th>Tues</th>
    <th>Wed</th>
    <th>Thurs</th>
    <th>Fri</th> 
    <th>Sat</th> 
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">6</td></div>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">24</td></div>
    <td>25</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>28</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  
 <table class="Calendar">
  <tr>
  <th colspan="7">October 2021</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Sun</th> 
    <th>Mon</th>
    <th>Tues</th>
    <th>Wed</th>
    <th>Thurs</th>
    <th>Fri</th> 
    <th>Sat</th> 
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">11</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">12</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">13</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">14</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">15</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">16</td></div>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td><div class="eventDay">17</td></div>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>28</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>30</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>31</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  
  <table class="Calendar">
  <tr>
  <th colspan="7">November 2021</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Sun</th> 
    <th>Mon</th>
    <th>Tues</th>
    <th>Wed</th>
    <th>Thurs</th>
    <th>Fri</th> 
    <th>Sat</th> 
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">11</td></div>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">24</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">25</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">26</td></div>
    <td>27</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>28</td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">29</td></div>
    <td>30</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  
 <table class="Calendar">
<tr>
  <th colspan="7">December 2021</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Sun</th> 
    <th>Mon</th>
    <th>Tues</th>
    <th>Wed</th>
    <th>Thurs</th>
    <th>Fri</th> 
    <th>Sat</th> 
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">1</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">2</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">3</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">4</td></div>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td><div class="eventDay">5</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">6</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">7</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">8</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">9</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">10</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">11</td></div>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td><div class="eventDay">12</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">13</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">14</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">15</td></div>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">25</td></div>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td><div class="eventDay">26</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">27</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">28</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">29</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">30</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">31</td></div>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
 </th>
 </div>
 </div>
</div>
```